# Map Algebra - Grass GIS (r.mapcalc) merge two raster with NoData value

Tags: raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I have a slope raster and a road raster. The black pixels in the road raster are NoData values and the pink pixels have a value of 1. They don't cover exactly the same area.
[image]

I want to create a new raster based on the slope raster, except for pixels where there is a road pixel. If there is a road pixel, I want to assign a value of zero to the slope raster.

I am not quite sure how the formula needs to look like.
I tried the following, put it didn't give me the expected results:

`r.mapcalc "output = ((Slope+(Road*null())))"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `r.mapcalc` expression:

```
r.mapcalc "output = not(if(Road))*Slope"
```

because:

- `if(Road)`is equal to 1 if `Road` not zero, 0 otherwise.
- `not(if(Road))`is equal to 0 if `Road` not zero, 1 otherwise.

Comment: Though the part of the Slope Raster not covered by the Road Raster gets cut off. Is there a way to keep that part?

Comment: You could use `r.patch` before in order to make the Road raster cover the lower part of the Slope raster.

Comment: more simply, `g.region rast=slope`.

Comment: Note that for GRASS 7, the command should be `r.mapcalc "output = not(if(Road))*Slope"` (both spaces and quotes are needed).

Comment: @wenzeslaus Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the answer.