# Merge raster layers with NoData cells

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, merge, overlapping-features, mosaic

I have two elevation rasters that I want to combine into an output like the one shown in the image - *Expected result*.

I tried that using `Gdal: Merge`, but it doesn't take into account my NoData cells as seen in *Merge - Result*.

[image]

From what I understand from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76004/map-algebra-grass-gis-r-mapcalc-merge-two-raster-with-nodata-value) question, it is possible to do that using GRASS's tool `r.mapcalculator`. I tried the solution listed there, but it outputs only a few pixels where the two rasters overlap.

How can I adapt the code below to match my needs?

```
r.mapcalc "output = not(if(a))*b"
```

I am open to other suggestions as well.

I am using QGIS 2.14 with GRASS 7.0.4.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but `gdal_merge` can take into account NoData values with the `-n` option for the input and `-a_nodata` for the output ([official doc](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)).

Comment: You're right, thank you. Actually I was using `gdal: Merge` from the QGIS GUI and it didn't have the option for NoData. But I've used `gdal_merge` and it worked perfectly. Now I don't know if I should leave the question here or just delete it.

Comment: I would suggest leaving the question open and @ArMoraer posting an answer :)

Comment: A solution using `r.mapcalculator` is still welcome, because `gdal_merge` stops my automated script with a "Python.exe has stopped working" error, as seen [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/479), [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101921/gdal-calc-works-but-i-get-a-python-error-at-the-end-of-each-process-that-prevent) and [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/466).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve this is using `gdal_merge.py`. But unfortunately, this tool stops my automated script with a "*Python.exe has stopped working*" error, as others complained [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/479), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101921/gdal-calc-works-but-i-get-a-python-error-at-the-end-of-each-process-that-prevent) and [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/466).

Another option, which actually works for me, is using `SAGA`'s tool `Mosaic raster layers`, which doesn't generate any errors:

```
#prepare QGIS environment
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("E:\\QGIS\\apps\\qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

#prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('E:\\QGIS\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing
from processing.tools import *

#set variables
algorithm = "saga:mosaickrasterlayers"
inputMain = path + "Flood_main.tif;"
input2D = path + "Flood_cvasi2D.tif"
addInput = None
dataType = 7
interpolation = 0
overlapAreas = 1
blendDistance = 10
match = 0
fit = 0
extent = "612550.33,660022.33,679329.28,703773.28"
result = path + "Flood.tif"

#run algorithm
processing.runalg(algorithm,inputMain + input2D, addInput, dataType, interpolation,
                  overlapAreas, blendDistance, match, fit, extent, result)

#exit QGIS
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

**QGIS version**: 2.14.3-Essen

Comment: saga mosaickrasterlayers als oworks well!

Answer (score 0):

Copy of this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/425197/92995 In QGIS/processing, use the GRASS tool "r.series". As "Aggregate operation" choose "average"/"median"/"minimum" or "maximum" to deal with overlaps

The tool also conveniently can be set to ignore values above/below set values (useful in eliminating a NULL value of e.g. -9999, so it does not affect the results).

I think raster have to be same CRS, but can be different extend and different resolution.